# EDITED: Updating BackgroundEffectsBehavior/Cory Plott's image effects through code (WPF/C#) .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, shader

EDIT: I've narrowed the problem down to the BackgroundEffectsBehavior, which is used by Cory Plott's image effects to blend a path into the background. It creates the image during the creation of the image object/imagebrush object. What I could try now is updating the behavior through a method, and I've even done around 2 hours of research into doing this, but nothing's turned up. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm currently using Cory Plott's blend mode library for fancy effects in my application. The effects themselves look good. But there's this weird disjointed problem between an UI element and an image. [The blue circle shows where there's a weird discontinuity between the image and the overlay image (the white part of the image in the bar at the bottom shouldn't be showing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpIln.png)

This isn't right because it's essentially creating the overlay during the `InitializeComponent();` method, which is called during `mainWindow.showDialog`. This makes everything squished together. So I figured that I'd run an refresh method that updates on every window resize because that's where the problem is right now. Then I wrote this method to do it

```
            BehaviorCollection behaviorCollection = Interaction.GetBehaviors(TopBar);
           // behaviorCollection.RemoveAt(0);
            BackgroundEffectBehavior backgroundEffectBehavior = new                 BackgroundEffectBehavior();
            backgroundEffectBehavior.Visual = TopBar;
            OverlayEffect overlayEffect = new OverlayEffect();
            GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing();
            geometryDrawing.Geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0,0,1,1));
            Color color = new Color();
            color.A = 255;
            color.R = 88;
            color.G = 88;
            color.B = 88;
            geometryDrawing.Brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
            DrawingImage drawingImage = new DrawingImage();
            drawingImage.Drawing = geometryDrawing;
            ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
            imageBrush.ImageSource = drawingImage;
            overlayEffect.BInput = imageBrush;                                            
            BlendModeEffect blendModeEffect = new OverlayEffect();;
            backgroundEffectBehavior.Effect = blendModeEffect;
            behaviorCollection.Add(backgroundEffectBehavior);
            Console.WriteLine("resized");
```

This is essentially a translation of the XAML code into c#. But the problem right now is that it makes the "TopBar" rectangle which contains the blended image disappear. Why is that?

TL,DR: Why is this long method making my "TopBar" disappear.